# How to run a Cypress test several times in a row by modifying only one variable out of several?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I am creating my first cypress tests for the first time to test an endpoint.
This is the login.js

```
Given(
  "Request to login in correct {string} with {string} and {string}, valid {string} and {string}",
  (country, mail, password, token, udid) => {
    cy.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: `${Cypress.env("BASE_URL")}/api/login`,
      failOnStatusCode: false,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${Cypress.env(cvp)}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "MRKT": country,
      },
      body: {
        email: Cypress.env(mail),
        password: Cypress.env(password),
        udid: Cypress.env(udid),
      },
    }).as("login");
  }
);


Then("Status Code is {int}", (statusCode) => {
  cy.get("@login").should((response) => {
    expect(response.status).to.eq(statusCode);
  });
});
```

and this is the login.feature

```
@login

Scenario Outline: login  - Response 200
    Given Request to login in correct '<country>' with '<mail>' and '<password>', valid '<token>' and '<udid>'
    Then Status Code is 200
    Examples:
    | country | mail | password | token | udid |
    | US | US_MAIL | PASSWORD | US_TOKEN | NO_UDID |
    | UK | UK_MAIL | PASSWORD | UK_TOKEN | NO_UDID |
```

this is running perfectly, giving the desired result but now I'm stuck in a case where I want to pass the same user with different udid to test a device limitation error.
In this case I need to run 3 times the same data except the udid that must change in each of the executions to , after being 3 executions in a row , check that returns an error 429 (too many request).

Can I use the same js to test this case ?

An example of what I need to do is sometinhg like this:

```
@login

Scenario : login - Response 429 too many requests from

    Given Request to login in correct US with US_EMAIL and MAIL, and PASSWORD valid TOKEN and provided FIRST_UDID

    And Request to login in correct US with US_EMAIL and MAIL, and PASSWORD valid TOKEN and provided SECOND_UDID

    And Request to login in correct US with US_EMAIL and MAIL, and PASSWORD valid TOKEN and provided THIRD_UDID

    And Request to login in correct US with US_EMAIL and MAIL, and PASSWORD valid TOKEN and provided FOURTH_UDID

    Then Status Code is 429
```

or

```
Scenario : login - Response 429 too many requests 

    Given Request login in correct '<country>' with '<mail>' and '<password>', valid '<token>' and provided '<udid>'

        | country | mail | password | token | udid |

        | US | US_MAIL | PASSWORD | TOKEN | FIRST_UDID |

    And Request to login in correct '<country>' with '<mail>' and '<password>', valid '<token>' and provided '<udid>'

        | country | mail | password | token | udid |

        | US | US_MAIL | PASSWORD | TOKEN | SECOND_UDID |

    And Request to login in correct '<country>' with '<mail>' and '<password>', valid '<token>' and provided '<udid>'

        | country | mail | password | token | udid |

        | US | US_MAIL | PASSWORD | TOKEN | THIRD_UDID |

    And Request to login in correct '<country>' with '<mail>' and '<password>', valid '<token>' and provided '<udid>'

        | country | mail | password | token | udid |

        | US | US_MAIL | PASSWORD | TOKEN | FOURTH_UDID |

    Then Status Code is 429
```

How can I run the same test 3 times in a row and check the error right after?

Answer (score 2):

Each line in your `Examples:` should be considered a different independant test case. You should avoid linking cases using output from the previous `Examples:` line in the next `Examples:` line.
You should write a new `Scenario Outline:` for your `429` test since it has a different flow of actions.

```
@login

Scenario Outline: login  - Response 200
    Given Request to login in correct '<country>' with '<mail>' and '<password>', valid '<token>' and '<udid>'
    Then Status Code is 200
    Examples:
    | country | mail | password | token | udid |
    | US | US_MAIL | PASSWORD | US_TOKEN | NO_UDID |
    | UK | UK_MAIL | PASSWORD | UK_TOKEN | NO_UDID |

Scenario Outline: login - Response 429 (Too many requests)
    Given Request to login in correct '<country>' with '<mail>' and '<password>', valid '<token>' and '<udid1>'
    And   Request to login in correct '<country>' with '<mail>' and '<password>', valid '<token>' and '<udid2>'
    And   Request to login in correct '<country>' with '<mail>' and '<password>', valid '<token>' and '<udid3>'
    Then Status Code is 429
    Examples:
    | country | mail    | password | token    | udid1   | udid2   | udid3   |
    | US      | US_MAIL | PASSWORD | US_TOKEN | NO_UDID | NO_UDID | NO_UDID |
    | UK      | UK_MAIL | PASSWORD | UK_TOKEN | NO_UDID | NO_UDID | NO_UDID |
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach that makes me realize my mistake in my approach, I have updated the idea of what I need. Actually I only need to change one of the data in each of the calls but I don't know how to include the data in the test itself to take advantage of the existing JS, as you put in your example it doesn't work, debugging the values is returning the string (udid1, country, mail) and not picking the values from de cypress.env.

Answer (score 0):

I simply execute the same request as many times in a row as I need to, add the data directly and check the status after the number of requests needed.
I don't know if there is a better way to execute this case but it works perfectly.

```
    Given Request to login in correct 'US' with 'US_MAIL' and 'PASSWORD', valid 'US_TOKEN' and 'FIRST_UDID'

    Given Request to login in correct 'US' with 'US_MAIL' and 'PASSWORD', valid 'US_TOKEN' and 'SECOND_UDID'

    Given Request to login in correct 'US' with 'US_MAIL' and 'PASSWORD', valid 'US_TOKEN' and 'THIRD_UDID'

    Given Request to login in correct 'US' with 'US_MAIL' and 'PASSWORD', valid 'US_TOKEN' and 'FOURTH_UDID'

    Then Status Code is 429
```